# How do I order items in a function?

Tags: python, function, file

For my computing coursework, I had to create an arithmetic quiz which would save the users score in a file. I have completed this part but for the next task, I have to make the users names be printed in alphabetical order with their highest three scores showing. Then print highest to lowest score (showing which users got which score), and then find the average score of each user, and print the average scores in highest to lowest order (again showing which user got which score). Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it. Please help me. My code so far is this:

```
import random
from random import randint
import math
import fileinput

question = 0
ans = 0
score = 0

firstname = input("What is your first name?")
lastname = input("What is your last name?")
classofstudent = input("Which class are you in? (1,2 or 3?)")
print ("Welcome to this arithmetic quiz")
print ("")
for question in range(10):
    def multiplication():
        global ans
        numberOne, numberTwo = random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)
        print ("What is", numberOne, "*", numberTwo)
        ans = (numberOne * numberTwo)

    def subtraction():
        global ans
        numberOne, numberTwo = random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)
        print ("What is", numberOne, "-", numberTwo)
        ans = (numberOne - numberTwo)

    def addition():
        global ans
        numberOne, numberTwo = random.randint(0,10), random.randint(0,10)
        print ("What is", numberOne, "+", numberTwo)
        ans = (numberOne + numberTwo)

    operation = [multiplication, subtraction, addition]
    randoperation = random.choice(operation)
print()
def main():
    question = 0
    score = 0
    randoperation = random.choice(operation)

    whileTrue:
        try:
            randoperation()
            randoperation = random.choice(operation)
            if question >= 10:
                break

            userinput = int("What is your answer?")
            if userinput = ans:
                global score
                score = score + 1
                global question
                question += 1
                print ("Your answer is correct")
            else:
                print ("Incorrect")
                question += 1
        except ValueError:
            print ("Invalid answer")
            question += 1
        while question == 10:
            print (firstname ,lastname ,"you scored" , score,"/10")
            break
def filewrite():
    fileopen = open("data.txt", "a")
    counts = str(score)
    cos = str(classofstudent)
    Textline = (firstname + " " + lastname + " / class " + cos + " /score = " + counts + "/10" + "\n")
    fileopen.write(Textline)
    fileopen.close

def read():
    with open ('data.txt') as data:
        print ("")
        for line in data:
            print (line, end ='')
        print ("")
    check = "Y"

main() 
filewrite()
read()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start by reading your results into a list or dictionary and use the `sorted()` function to order the elements in alphabetical, ascending or descending orders.

```
>>> elements = [22, 333, 0, -22, 1000]
>>> print sorted(elements)
[-22, 0, 22, 333, 1000]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> for element in reversed(sorted(elements)):
...     print element
... 
1000
333
22
0
-22
```

Check out this tutorial about [Sorting](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).